# Clojure: ns-resolve -> get an agent -> call send on it

Tags: clojure

Minimal failure case:

```
(ns test)

(def a (agent "hello"))

(send a (fn [x] "world")) ; works

(send (ns-resolve 'test 'a) (fn [x] "test")) ; fails
```

Question:

Why does the last line fail?

This is part of a code hot-loading system. I have to use ns-resolve.

Is there a way to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ns-resolve returns a var, not the value of the var (the agent). you need to deref the var to get the value:

```
(send (deref (ns-resolve 'test 'a)) (fn [x] "world"))
;; or
(send @(ns-resolve 'test 'a) (fn [x] "world"))
```